# On which spaces can lower semicontinuous functions be approximated from below by bounded continuous functions?

Tags: functional-analysis, semicontinuous-functions

On metric spaces this can obviously be done by defining $F_n$ as in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3490248/lower-semicontinuous-function-supremum-of-sequence-of-continuous-functions?rq=1) and then e.g setting $G_n(x) = \min \{ F_n ( x ), n \}$.

But what if the space in question is not metrisable? In my case I have a nuclear space, but I suspect that this should be possible on a much broader class of spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has a clear answer in [enter link description here](https://doi.org/10.1215/S0012-7094-52-01928-5).
The correct category is that of [perfectly normal spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_space).